Confused about OAuth / OAuth 2 and our current requirement
We use Mulesoft 4.x to develop our API and call a lot of 3rd party API
Most of these APi we call by passing in client_id and client_secret as headers over HTTPS to authenticate
Recently 2 of these 3rd party API have / are mandating changes .
#1 for one of the API , now rather than send client id and secret to their endpoints , we are now doing the following :

First we call a token endpoiint by passing in client id and secret and get back an access token
This token will remain valid for 7 minutes
To call their endpoints we now pass this valid token as a Authorisation header and things work fine
We have logic implemented at our end ( caching ) to ensure that we regenerate the token 1 minute before it expires and things are working fine

Now coming to the second 3rd party api :

We are integrating with Workday api and here it is a little different ....
First we call a token endpoint by passing in client id and client secret AND a refresh token provided by Workday ( grant_type=refresh_token )
This will return us an access token ( has been defined in Workday to expire every 1 day )
We then use this access token to invoke workday endpoints

Note 1 - this is a server to server ( api to api ) communication and no browser or front end is involved , we are processing data as a batch process
Note 2 : am trying to read up about OAuth here and here
To quote from one of the above links :

A refresh token is another type of token, which is used behind the scenes to generate a new access token once expired. So upon the initial request, the authorization server will now return both an access token and a refresh token (which is basically another JWT only with a much longer lifetime). When the access token is expired, the client will issue another request, now of grant type refresh_token, and after validation, it will get back a new access token and replace the old one with it. This happens without involving the user, and so we can keep scrolling our Instagram....

when I look at the two implementations - the workday one seems a little strange....

Why do we have a refresh token   ?
if on expiry of access token we need to send client id , secret and refresh token then how is this more secure than just sending client id and secret  ?

